# Passbook changeMessage displaying user friendly URL

Tags: apple-push-notifications, android-pay, passbook, wallet

Lets imagine I have a backField with data below:

```
{
    key:"key-1",
    attributedValue:"<a href='https://somewhere.com'>Link</a>",
    changeMessage: "Key-1 field changed:%@"
}
```

I wish to display user friendly - `Key-1 field changed:Link` at the lock screen when push notification arrives, instead of - `Key-1 field changed:<a href='https://somewhere.com'>Link</a>`.

Is there any option to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove changeMessage from your back field.

Now, create a special back field with the content of your push message and set its changeMessage to %@.

Comment: So in my case I will have to add a saparate backField with next data: `{
    key:"key-333",
    value:"Link",
    changeMessage: "%@"
}`
And in that case both back fields will appear in pass, one with the real link and one with the text- `Link`.

Comment: @Maris where should I add this link in pass.json ?  can you please give example

Comment: @M.A Just add it to Backfields.

Comment: @Maris thanks for your response. this is how your saying ? `{
        "key": "memberid",
        "value": "",
        "label": "ID# 123456",
 "textAlignment" : "PKTextAlignmentLeft"
      }
    ],
    "backFields": [
      {
        "label": "MOBILE TERMS:",
        "key": "info",
  "value" : "MOBILE TERMS ",
      changeMessage: "%@" 
      
   }
    ]`

Comment: Console : `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [30/Jun/2017:09:34:42 -0700] "GET /push.php HTTP/1.1" 200 188
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [30/Jun/2017:09:34:43 -0700] "GET /v1/devices/af56c0d12bdbnf6kkatt3aa5c10d0dg64/registrations/pass.test.com.mymobileDomain?passesUpdatedSince=2017-06-30%2009:23:06 HTTP/1.1" 200 68
`

Comment: @M.A Yeap and if you then will send a push notification and change the Backfields to: 
`[ { "label": "MOBILE TERMS:", "key": "info", "value" : "New cool mobile terms", changeMessage: "%@" } ]` users will receive a popup message - `New cool mobile terms`

Comment: @Maris  you are great.. one question you have any idea about this maybe you also encounter. im able to push new changes but doesn't appear on phone until I disable my auto update and enable ?

Comment: @M.A we have faced a lot of problems depending on platform/wallet application on platform/tons of different configuration on phone or wallet application/roaming settings/internet availability. Just keep in mind that you cannot guarantee that your customer will receive in push notification. Real facts about our experience, we have >100k passes in production, consumed by ~150k users and only ~145k end-users receives push notifications. You should leave with that pain. There is also tons of wallet specific things, you will find them in your development path. Good luck! :)

Comment: @M.A BTW, you can find my skype account in my profile. Feel free to contact in a case of questions.

Comment: Just Added on skype ... thank you so much... my problem is if im able to push new card only one time on one device successfully it will be great. i have no problem if 1k pushed 800 able to receive. minimum i know my code is working.